# How to find manually some event and I/O related information in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used Oracle 11g SE version database and it doesn't have the diagnostics and tuning package. So whenever I run an AWR Report for a specific date and time, the below entries are displayed as blank.

[image]

Based on the image above, can anyone please help me with how to find statistics for some data for a specific time like 10:00 AM to 12:00 AM?

Additionally, are there any other supported third party tools which can solve my issue?

Comment: Statspack is the precursor to AWR and gives you similar information.  You'd need to install that if it is not already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's data dictionary has dynamic performance views:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_part.htm#REFRN003

The topic quickly gets deep. @justin cave has a good suggestion; statspack

Try: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/statspack-examples/